# i am getting issue during login in my wordpress website showing not acceptable issue

Tags: wordpress

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R1f8l.png)

i am getting issue during login in my WordPress website showing the not acceptable issue the statment is " An appropriate representation of the requested resource could not be found on this server. This error was generated by Mod_Security."

Answer (score 0):

Not accepted issue rise when your ipv4 got blacklist by your hosting, the only method to solve this to whitelist your IPV4 from your c penal if not then connect to your hosting chat support they will do that for you